# Using if statements on two XML documents

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xquery, oxygenxml

I have two XML docs Students.xml and Admission.xml, I need a xquery to return the Student ID and Student Name of students who have completed 30 days from the admission date. I am confused on how to join them and to use a condition to come up with,please help.

The Student.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<StudentDetails>
    <Student_ID>1</Student_ID>
    <Student_Name>Mark</Student_Name>
</StudentDetails>
<StudentDetails>
    <Student_ID>2</Student_ID>
    <Student_Name>Robin</Student_Name>
</StudentDetails>
<StudentDetails>
    <Student_ID>3</Student_ID>
    <Student_Name>Charlie</Student_Name>
</StudentDetails>
</root>
```

The Admission.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
<AdmissionDetails>
    <Admission_ID>1</Admission_ID>
    <Admission_Date>2017-10-06</Admission_Date>
    <Admission_Status>Admitted</Admission_Status>
    <Student_ID>3</Student_ID>
</AdmissionDetails>
<AdmissionDetails>
    <Admission_ID>2</Admission_ID>
    <Admission_Date>2017-04-14</Admission_Date>
    <Admission_Status>Admitted</Admission_Status>
    <Student_ID>2</Student_ID>
</AdmissionDetails>
<AdmissionDetails>
    <Admission_ID>3</Admission_ID>
    <Admission_Date>2017-08-16</Admission_Date>
    <Admission_Status>Admitted</Admission_Status>
    <Student_ID>1</Student_ID>
</AdmissionDetails>
```

My code so far is this but it gives me a result which is a repetition of values, need help desperately.

```
for $sid in doc("Student.xml")/root/StudentDetails/Student_ID
for $aid  in doc("Admission.xml")/root/AdmissionDetails/Student_ID
for $x in doc("Admission,xml")/root/AdmissionDetails/Admission_Date
where $sid = $aid and $x >current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")
return  $sid
```

And this is the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Student_ID>1</Student_ID>
<Student_ID>1</Student_ID>
<Student_ID>10</Student_ID>
<Student_ID>10</Student_ID>
```

Comment: Any reference to existing blogs or answers would also help much, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're falling into the trap of thinking that every query has to be a FLWOR expression (it's generally a sign that you've spent too long writing SQL).

I would write this as:

```
    let $S30 := doc("Admission.xml")/*/Admission_Details
        [xs:date(Admission_Date) < current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D")]
        /Admission_ID
    return doc("Student.xml")/*/StudentDetails[Student_ID = $S30]
```

Comment: Hi Michael, You are right, i have spent too long writing SQL and your code worked, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over each of the `StudentDetails` in the Students.xml documents, and then filter WHERE the `StudentDetails/Student_ID` value is equal to an Admission.xml `AdmissionDetails` element's `Student_ID` and has an `Admission_Date` that meets your criteria (*are you sure that is the correct date filter? Your description says Completion Date within 30 days of Admission, but the sample data does not have a Completion Date, only the Admission Date*), and then return the `Student_ID` and `Student_Name` from those students that satisfy the WHERE clause conditions.

```
for $student in doc("Student.xml")/root/StudentDetails
where doc("Admission.xml")/root/AdmissionDetails[
        Student_ID = $student/Student_ID and 
        xs:date(Admission_Date) < current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration("P30D") 
      ]
return 
  ($student/Student_ID, $student/Student_Name)
```

The XQuery specification has examples of "inner" and "outer" [joins](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xquery-31-20170321/#id-joins) that might be informative.